# no triggering on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

This is a simple but intersting issue. Suppose I have two sections of respective class `.toggle0` and `.toggle1`, suppose I want to display `.toggle0` and hide `.toggle1` when clicking on some tag `.footer0`, and vice-versa : I want to display `.toggle1` and hide `.toggle0` when clicking on some tag `.footer1`. Now this code works correctly

```
$('.toggle1').hide();
  var i=0;
    $(".footer"+i+"").click(function(){
        $(".toggle"+(i+1) %2+"").hide();
        $(".toggle"+i+"").show();
    });
  var j=1;
    $(".footer"+j+"").click(function(){
        $(".toggle"+(j+1) %2+"").hide();
        $(".toggle"+j+"").show();
    });
```

but this doesn't work in the sense that nothing happens on click event

```
for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
    $(".footer"+i+"").click(function(){
            $(".toggle"+(i+1) %2+"").hide();
            $(".toggle"+i+"").show();
        });
}
```

if I put this

```
      $('.toggle1').hide();
      var i=0;
        $(".footer"+i+"").click(function(){
            $(".toggle"+(i+1) %2+"").hide();
            $(".toggle"+i+"").show();
        });
       i =1;
        $(".footer"+i+"").click(function(){
            $(".toggle"+(i+1) %2+"").hide();
            $(".toggle"+i+"").show();
        });
```

`.toggle1` displays and `.toggle0` hides when clicking on some tag `.footer1` but  `.toggle0` does not display and `.toggle1` does not hide when clicking on some tag `.footer0` . It seems that the second click event takes precedence upon the first

Comment: log `i` inside your click event. It isn't what you think it is. Why are you using enumerated classes? there has to be a better way.

Comment: Have you considered using relative selectors next(), previous(), parent(), find() and doing away with using class names completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i` within the the click handler isn't evaluated until a click, at which point the value has changed from when the handler was bound. If you want to go this route, you need to create a closure. Here's one method to do so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    $(".footer" + i + "").click(function () {
        var idx = i;
        return function () {
            $(".toggle"+(idx+1) %2+"").hide();
            $(".toggle"+idx+"").show();
            console.log(idx);
        }
    }());
}
```

Comment: IN fact, the console logs the correct values, but the show() and hide() method doesn't work !

Comment: Whoops, copied the code from your question with `i` instead of `idx`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.footer0').click(function(){
  $('.toggle0 .toggle1').hide();
  $('.toggle0').show();
});
$('.footer1').click(function(){
  $('.toggle0 .toggle1').hide();
  $('.toggle1').show();
});
```